# why does the cursor exit when there is null value in the column

Tags: plsql

```
create or replace procedure data_quality_check( inface_id number default null)  is
v_src_clmn varchar2(400);
v_tgt_clmn varchar2(400);
v2_src_value varchar2(400);
date_chk varchar2(200);
v2_primary_key varchar2(400);

CURSOR cur_1 is select temp_field_name,dest_field_name,transform_function from BUNTERFACETEMP_TO_DEST where BUNTERFACEID = inface_id;
c_curr1 cur_1%ROWTYPE;

/* Second cursor */
TYPE cur_typ IS REF CURSOR;
cur_2 cur_typ;


begin

execute immediate 'truncate table BUNTERFACEDATA_QLTY_CHK';

open cur_1;
loop
FETCH cur_1 INTO v_src_clmn,v_tgt_clmn,date_chk;



if date_chk = 'bingle.txt2dt' OR date_chk = 'bingle.txt2dtf1'  OR date_chk = 'bingle.txt2dtf2' OR date_chk = 'bingle.txt2dtf3' then  
  -- Open second cursor
      OPEN cur_2 for 'SELECT C2,' || v_src_clmn || ' from  CAT_TEMP_MED' ;
      LOOP
      FETCH cur_2 INTO v2_primary_key,v2_src_value;
      EXIT when  cur_1%NOTFOUND;  
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( v_src_clmn || '-' || v2_src_value || inface_id || date_chk);
                Insert into  BUNTERFACEDATA_QLTY_CHK(pk_key,temp_field_name,BUNTERFACEID,DEST_FIELD_NAME,VALUE,ERROR,date_loaded)  values (v2_primary_key,
           v_src_clmn,inface_id,v_tgt_clmn,v2_src_value,'GOOD ROW',sysdate);

         IF v2_src_value is NULL then 
            Insert into BUNTERFACEDATA_QLTY_CHK(pk_key,temp_field_name,BUNTERFACEID,DEST_FIELD_NAME,VALUE,ERROR,date_loaded)  values (v2_primary_key,
           v_src_clmn,inface_id,v_tgt_clmn,v2_src_value,'NULL VALUE',sysdate);
           commit; 
           exit;
        end if;
      EXIT when  cur_2%NOTFOUND;  
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE cur_2;
end if;   

end loop;
close cur_1;
end;
```

In the above cursor as soon as the null value is encountered the cursor exit.
What is the reason for it?
I am struggling from morning for this
Any alternate solution

The above code fetches column name from table  BUNTERFACETEMP_TO_DEST and than verifies the column value is null or not.
is it null than it insert the data into table but what I am seeing is as soon as null is encountered the loop exit.

Comment: Write an exception and catch it and share it here so that anyone can help

Comment: what should i write in exception sorry I thought exception is catching for error.

Answer (score 0):

You have an early unconditional `exit` within the loop:

```
LOOP
  ...
    IF v2_src_value is NULL then 
       Insert into BUNTERFACEDATA_QLTY_CHK ...;
       commit; 
       **exit;**
    end if;
```

The first time the loop encounters a null, your code will exit the loop.